# Do I need Angular CLI to develop Angular apps?

Tags: angular

Just joined a project where they're using Angular and I can see in the *package.json* file these dependencies:

```
"@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^8.0.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
```

But if I type in *ng -v* then I get a *command not found* error. I'm guessing it's because I don't have the Angular CLI installed. Do I need it? Seems like I don't. What will I be unable to do without having the Angular CLI package installed?

PS - I'm using *NVM*.

Thanks for any helpful info.

Comment: No you do not need angular-cli. Without it, you won’t be able to run angular-cli commands.

Comment: ...commands like "ng ...whatever..", right?

Comment: https://angular.io/cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need it, but it is good to create component and modules fast with `ng g` option and building or serving the project.

To fix your error of running `ng -v` you need to install angular-cli globally, like that:
`npm install -g angular-cli`

If you want to use your local angular-cli, you can run this:
`npm run-script ng -v` and you will see the local angular-cli version instead of the global